# Login Controller and View

Tags: cakephp-2.0

```
 I have been on this login part of my program for a while  but i have just been failing..I am just so tired of this thing...Please how do you do login controller and view for cakephp?...I have tried and tried but it still doesnt work...please HELP!!!
```

This is my login view.ctp

```
          <html>
          <body background="bgimage.jpg">
          <center>
           <strong><h2>LOGIN FORM</h2><strong>

           <?php 
                echo $this->form->create('Login', array('action' => 'login'));
                echo $this->form->input('Username'); ?>  <br>
               <?php echo $this->form->input('Password'); ?> <br>
                <?php echo $this->form->end('Login');
                    ?>
                   <br><br>
         <?php echo $this->html->link ('Forgot Password?',array('action'=>'forgot')); ?>
          </center>

     <p><?php echo $this->html->link ('Create Account', array('action' =>'add')); ?></p>
             </body>
          </html>
```

And this isthe login function in my controller code:

```
function login() {
$this->loadModel('User');


$this->request->data['MyModel']['username'];
$this->request->data['MyModel']['title'];

    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'home'));

     if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl('home'));
        // `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());`
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(
            __('Username or password is incorrect'),
            'default',
            array(),
            'auth'
        );
    }

          }
```

PLEASE, am i doing anything wrong?
Please how do you do login controller and view for cakephp?

Comment: What is your controller name or which controller did you put your login function?

Comment: I am using  "UsersController"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the below code should be in app/View/Users/login.ctp not view.ctp and use below code and see some of the adjustment I made.

```
  <html>
  <body background="bgimage.jpg">
  <center>
   <strong><h2>LOGIN FORM</h2><strong>
       <?php 
            echo $this->form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
            echo $this->form->input('username'); // please use your 'username' as you put in the database?>  <br>
           <?php echo $this->form->input('password'); // please use your 'password' as you put in the database ?> <br>
            <?php echo $this->form->end('Login');
                ?>
               <br><br>
     <?php echo $this->html->link ('Forgot Password?',array('action'=>'forgot')); ?>
      </center>

 <p><?php echo $this->html->link ('Create Account', array('action' =>'add')); ?></p>
         </body>
      </html>
```

and then in the below function should be in app/Controller/UsersController.php

```
function login() {
//$this->loadModel('User'); no need to use this as you are in UsersController.php


//$this->request->data['MyModel']['username']; you don't need this
//$this->request->data['MyModel']['title']; you don't need this

    //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'home')); why do you want to redirect here, if you redirect here, it'll not come to login page at first

     if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
$this->redirect(array('action' => 'home'));//redirect should be here        
//return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl('home'));
        // `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());`
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(
            __('Username or password is incorrect'),
            'default',
            array(),
            'auth'
        );
    }

      }
```

Before all this, you should have 'Auth' component in your AppController.php, for more information, you should see [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html)